# Is this ActiveMQ "Classic" usecase possible in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to convert an application from ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis but it seems like it is going to require a redesign to use ActiveMQ Artemis.

I have a server which services a number of clients via an ActiveMQ "Classic" broker. Each client manages multiple sessions and the sending API they use creates a queue for each session, e.g. `clientname.session1234`. The session name is free-format and the client decides it.

On ActiveMQ "Classic" this is simple. The server listens to the producer advisories for all queues and when the first producer is added then a listener is created. Then when the last producer is removed the listener is removed. This frees up the broker to garbage collect the queue and resources are neatly cleaned up.

On ActiveMQ Artemis there is no management notification (Artemis' equivalent of advisories) for a producer being added/removed. It doesn't look like there is a concept of producers. I can handle the creation of listeners on arbitrary queues by implementing a handshake message on a known queue indicating "I'm sending on queue x.x.x", but I can't guarantee that a client will exit orderly to implement a handshake for "I'm no longer sending on queue x.x.x."

With no tracking of producers I can never know if I can remove a consumer, hence a queue is never auto-deleted and I end up leaking resources.

The only options I see are to redesign to move to known queue names with the session name as an attribute. I don't like that as I want to flow control each session. Or implement a thread to monitor message counts on queues and create/remove listeners as appropriate, which has it's own problems.

I wonder if any ActiveMQ Artemis experts can suggest a way of replicating something similar to the ActiveMQ "Classic" scenario.

Comment: Do you plan on still using your OpenWire JMS clients with ActiveMQ Artemis or are you going to migrate to the core JMS client (or some other client)?

Comment: For what it's worth, this isn't a great question for StackOverflow as it's likely to generate a fair bit of discussion and opinion-based answers rather than fact-based answers. Perhaps you could re-word it to ask a more concrete question about a particular implementation idea you want to pursue. Otherwise it's at risk of being closed. Check out the [ActiveMQ website](https://activemq.apache.org/contact) for more ways to connect with the community with open-ended questions like this.

Comment: Most of the protocols supported by ActiveMQ Artemis (and, in fact, ActiveMQ "Classic") don't actually have the concept of a *producer* as an entity that's registered on the broker. It makes sense to register a consumer on the broker because the broker is responsible for dispatching messages to the consumer. AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, and core all just support sending messages anonymously. Historically, only OpenWire actually sends a command to the broker indicating that the client is creating a producer. Support for this was recently added to core as well but only for tracking purposes.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Justin, sorry for the delay, i was away. Yes it was planned to keep the existing clients, if we had to make significant changes to the server and client side we'd probably stick with classic., I had hoped that Artemis supporting OpenWire would mean a simple port. Thanks for the info on the suitability of the question and The link to the AMQ mailing list .

Comment: If Artemis' OpenWire implementation doesn't send an advisory when a producer is created then that's a gap that should be fixed. Once that's addressed I think your use-case would work just fine, right?

Comment: There was a jira raised for such but it was closed as 'won't fix' https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-796